# Cancel Task in await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task, cancellation

I'm playing with tasks, and I don't know how to cancel task when Exception is thrown. I am trying with `TaskCompletionSourcecancel` but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to completely halt the task when Exception is thrown?

```cs
public async Task Migrate()
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    if (IsDataMigratorItemParameteresCorrect())
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection srcconnection = this.SourceConnection)
            {
                await srcconnection.OpenAsync();
                using (SqlCommand srccmd = CreateMigrateTaskCommand(this.SourceForHash, srcconnection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader srcreader = await srccmd.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess))
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection destconnection = this.DestinationConnection)
                        {
                           await destconnection.OpenAsync();

                           await CreateStageTable(destconnection, srcreader);
                           await BulkCopy(destconnection, srcreader);
                           await Merge(destconnection, srcreader);
                           await DropTable(destconnection); 
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DestinationCommand + " canceled\nException : " + ex.Message);
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        }
    }
}

private SqlCommand CreateMigrateTaskCommand(string commandQuery, SqlConnection connection)
{
    SqlCommand scmd = new SqlCommand(commandQuery, connection);
    return scmd;
}

private async Task Merge(SqlConnection conn, SqlDataReader reader)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdMerge = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        string mergeQuery = SqlGenerator.BuildMergeQuery(reader, DestinationCommand, this.SourceUniqueKey, this.DestinationUniqueKey);

        cmdMerge.CommandText = mergeQuery;
        cmdMerge.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdMerge.CommandTimeout = 0;
        await cmdMerge.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - MERGE START\n", DestinationCommand);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - MERGE SUCCESS!\n", DestinationCommand);
}

private async Task BulkCopy(SqlConnection conn, SqlDataReader reader)
{
    using (SqlBulkCopy bcp = new SqlBulkCopy(conn.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)) //table lock
    {
        bcp.SqlRowsCopied += bcp_SqlRowsCopied;
        bcp.BatchSize = this.BatchSize;
        bcp.EnableStreaming = true;
        bcp.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
        bcp.NotifyAfter = 1000;

        string destTable = this.DestinationCommand + "_stage";
        bcp.DestinationTableName = destTable;

        await bcp.WriteToServerAsync(reader);
    }
}

private async Task CreateStageTable(SqlConnection conn, SqlDataReader reader)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdCreateTable = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            string createTableQuery = SqlGenerator.BuildCreateTableQuery(reader, this.DestinationCommand);

            cmdCreateTable.CommandText = createTableQuery;
            cmdCreateTable.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            await cmdCreateTable.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(this.DestinationCommand + " created!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}

private async Task DropTable(SqlConnection conn)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdCreateTable = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            string tableName = DestinationCommand + "_stage";
            var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder();
            string escapedTableName = builder.QuoteIdentifier(tableName);
            cmdCreateTable.CommandText = "drop table " + escapedTableName;
            Console.WriteLine(escapedTableName + " created!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DestinationCommand + " canceled\nException : " + ex.Message);
            tcs.SetCanceled();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code example is not complete.

Comment: My bad. Edited now :)

Answer (score 4):

There are two parts to [cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997364(v=vs.110).aspx): requesting the cancellation (`TaskCompletionSource.SetCanceled`) and responding to that cancellation request.

Your code is calling `SetCanceled` when an exception occurs, which is OK if you want to cancel *other* operations when *that* one has an exception.

However, nothing in the code is listening to the cancellation token. It should be passed to APIs that support `CancellationToken`, or periodically checked (`CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested`), or have a cancellation callback attached to it (`CancellationToken.Register`). Otherwise, it's just a flag that is set and no one is checking it.